# How to get the average of several chrono::time_points

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-chrono

The formula for getting the average of several numbers is of course well known:

[image]

And this formula can easily be used to get the average of `chrono::duration`s:

```
template <class Rep0, class Period0>
auto
sum(const std::chrono::duration<Rep0, Period0>& d0)
{
    return d0;
}

template <class Rep0, class Period0, class ...Rep, class ...Period>
auto
sum(const std::chrono::duration<Rep0, Period0>& d0,
    const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& ...d)
{
    return d0 + sum(d...);
}

template <class ...Rep, class ...Period>
auto
avg(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& ...d)
{
    return sum(d...) / static_cast<std::common_type_t<Rep...>>(sizeof...(d));
}
```

But `chrono::time_point`s can't be added to one another.  How can I average `time_point`s?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It helps to start out with the assumption that you *can* add [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)s, and then manipulate the formula to eliminate those additions:

[image]

First separate out *t<sub>1</sub>* from the sum:

[image]

Next both add *and* subtract *t<sub>1</sub>*:

[image]

Factor and rearrange:

[image]

And then, since you are subtracting *t<sub>1</sub>* the same number of times as you are summing, you can include that into the sum:

[image]

Now you are summing [`duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)s *instead of* [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)s!  As we already have a function to sum [`duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)s, averaging [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)s can easily build on that:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration0, class ...Duration>
auto
avg(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration0>& t0,
    const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& ...t)
{
    constexpr auto N =
        static_cast<std::common_type_t<typename Duration0::rep,
                                       typename Duration::rep...>>(1 + sizeof...(t));
    return t0 + sum((t - t0)...) / N;
}
```

Averaging a single [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) is a special case since `sum` of [`duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)s does not handle summing zero [`duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)s (what would be the units?).  So an overload for that case is easily added:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration0>
auto
avg(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration0>& t0)
{
    return t0;
}
```

This is written in C++14.  It can be coded in C++11, using the [trailing return type declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) syntax, which is more verbose, but completely doable.

Comment: If anyone wants math-talk behind this, durations are vectors in a vector space (they support scaling, 0, and addition/subtraction) while time points are points in an affine space (they support *affine combinations* or "barycenter"s, basically weighted averages).  Real numbers are also a vector space, so our operations on them make sense in a vector space (and the overloads make sense).  We don't have such primitive math concepts that are affine spaces, so available notation is worse, and there aren't easy overloaded operators.

Comment: `sum(t0 - t0, (t - t0)...)` to handle the empty case is an alternative.

Comment: This has a subtle bug. If `rep` is signed, `t0 + sum((t - t0)...) / (1 + sizeof...(t))` is mixed arithmetic because `size_t` is an unsigned type. If `t0` is larger than average, the `sum` will be negative. `std::duration<std::int64_t>::operator/(size_t)` will use the common type, which for 64 bits `size_t` will cause a wrap-around to very large duration.

Comment: Good catch.  I'll throw in a static_cast.