# How do I average std::chrono::time_point?

Tags: c++, time

Given a vector of `std::chrono::time_point<Rep, Period>`, how do I find the average time_point?

The usual algorithm to find an average (add all values with `std::accumulate`, divide by the vector size) does not work because  you can't add two `std::chrono::time_point` values, nor can you divide a `std::chrono::time_point<Rep, Period>` by `vec.size()`

Comment: Average their `time_since_epoch()` and make a `time_point` from the result, perhaps?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48213002/576911

Comment: @HowardHinnant: The search didn't find that one, strangely enough. But it's a pretty direct duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the calculation in terms of a `std::chrono::duration`, such as `time_since_epoch`.

```
template<typename TimePoint>
TimePoint mean(auto&& range) {
    auto as_duration = std::views::transform(range, [](auto & tp){ return tp.time_since_epoch(); });
    return { std::accumulate(std::begin(as_duration), std::end(as_duration), {}) / std::size(range) };
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! As a side note, I would recommend subtracting a common mean, e.g. time_point 0, before the summation to reduce the risk of integer overflows in the summation. In pseudocode: average = sum(t1-t0, t2-t0, ...) / n + t0

Comment: The only problem is that for system clock `time_since_epoch` can be like 18 digits numbers held in an `int64` which can hold up to about 19 digits numbers. With this code you can get integer over with 10 timestamps.

Comment: @Homer512: You need the minimum, not t0. This is so the sum ends up being positive. If the sum is negative, you get a wrap-around when it's cast to `size_t` prior to dividing by `std::size(range)`. This gives very confusing results (it triggered a Y10K bug for me)

Comment: @MSalters Ha, good catch. I would cast size_t to ptrdiff_t instead. That avoids the minimum computation and since time_point is larger than 1 byte, there is no risk of overflowing during that cast.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between two time points is `std::chrono::duration`, and these types you can sum. So just take difference to the first element, averagize, and add the average to the first element. You'll get average timepoint.

Just make sure the durations you get don't get overflown after summing up. Consider casting to `std::chrono::duration<double>` but it might be over cautious.

Instead of taking difference vs first element you can also use `time_since_epoch()` but I don't recommend.